# Updating SQL database column based on rank

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm working on a program and one aspect is ranking each player based on their ELO score. I've been able to create a SQL query that can provide rankings as an output but I can't figure out how to make it actually update the database table. I am currently using SQLite

[image: Current Database Table]

Current Code:

```
SELECT
  name,
  elo,
  losses,
  matches,
  RANK() OVER(ORDER BY elo DESC)

FROM membersData
```

{[image: Ideal Database after update]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpio9.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please consider _not_ doing this update, as the rank you are computing is derived data.

Comment: Why the rank for 450 is above the rank for 123?

Comment: that is my mistake 450 should be 3, while 123 is 4th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that name is `unique`, so that we can join

```
 UPDATE membersData m1
 INNER JOIN (
 SELECT
  name,
  RANK() OVER(ORDER BY elo DESC) newrank FROM membersData) m2 ON m1.name = m2.name

SET m1.rank = m2.newrank
```

**Schema (SQLite v3.30)**

```
CREATE TABLE membersData(
    name    TEXT   ,
    elo     DOUBLE,
    wins    INTEGER,
    losses  INTEGER,
    matches INTEGER,
    ranking INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO membersData (
                            ranking,
                            matches,
                            losses,
                            wins,
                            elo,
                            name
                        )
                        VALUES (
                            NULL,
                            4,
                            3,
                            1,
                            123123,
                            'James'
                        ),
                        (
                            NULL,
                            5,
                            4,
                            1,
                            123,
                            'Top'
                        ),
                        (
                            NULL,
                            5,
                            2,
                            3,
                            1000,
                            'harry'
                        ),
                        (
                            NULL,
                            5,
                            0,
                            5,
                            450,
                            'kai'
                        );
```

---

**Query #1**

```
UPDATE membersData 
SET ranking = (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
                   FROM membersData md2
                   WHERE md2.elo > membersData.elo
                  );
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT * FROM membersData ORDEr BY ranking;
```

| name | elo | wins | losses | matches | ranking |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | 123123 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 1 |
| harry | 1000 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 2 |
| kai | 450 | 5 | 0 | 5 | 3 |
| Top | 123 | 1 | 4 | 5 | 4 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cW2X3hWFnGzfnKto4BgVnK/0)

Comment: Im new to sql, when executing this I get. [18:09:17] Error while executing SQL query on database 'chessClub': near "m1": syntax error. Name is also unique

Comment: xou have maybwe an error in your code, please make a dbfiddle, so that i can check that. You have changed the code.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cW2X3hWFnGzfnKto4BgVnK/0 . Does it work for sqlite?

Comment: @ArkieMandziy mysql 5.7 doesn't have rank, onply mysql 8.0 has it also you tagged your quuestion as sql lite, so i edited my answer to fit your requirements

Comment: You are a legend mate, I appreciate it immensely.

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery in the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE membersData md
    SET ranking = (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
                   FROM membersData md2
                   WHERE md2.elo > md.elo
                  );
```

Comment: @ArkieMandziy . . . Why not?